# Is there a safe way to call gettimeofday() from a Xenomai real time thread?

Tags: linux, kernel, gettimeofday, livelock, xenomai

I'm running a Xenomai real time thread that sometimes needs to call gettimeofday(), in order to find out what the current time is according to ptpd.

However, doing that appears to be unsafe:  in particular, it occasionally puts the Xenomai thread and the Linux kernel into a "livelock" situation, causing gettimeofday() to spin the CPU and never return, as described [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/xenomai-help@gna.org/msg10626.html).

My question is, is there a safe way to get gettimeofday()'s information from a Xenomai real time thread?  I'm considering adding my own version of gettimeofday() to my Linux kernel (my version would fail if read_seqretry() returns true, unlike the [regular version](http://www.google.com/codesearch#gufiwQeQ0iA/trunk/kernels/linux-2.6.16-gazineu/kernel/time.c&q=do_gettimeofday&type=cs&l=528) which will loop forever when that happens).  However, I'd just as soon not start customizing the Linux kernel if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: FWIW, Gilles from the Xenomai-help mailing list says that Xenomai 2.6 will have a CLOCK_HOSTRT clock feature that will satisfy this need.  For earlier versions, one work-around is to add an ioctl to a custom driver that returns the Linux real-time-clock without trying to loop if contention is detected.

Comment: can you put that as a detailed answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update Oct 2012** 
For anyone else stumbling across this thread...

Check the Xenomai API: 
http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/trunk/html/api/group__clock.html

Here's a code snippet for you, tested with Xenomai 2.6:

```
// Get system time in nanoseconds (real-time safe)
// Time is usually related to GMT, because Xenomai syncs time during
// bootup, so you might get a different time offset to gettimeofday()
// which is based on your current timezone. 
double time = (double)rt_timer_read(); 
time /= 1000000000; // convert to seconds
```

Comment: That is using the Xenomai Native API. There is another call in the Posix API that allows you to get the clock based on the host time.